# Fixing the Radial Axis on MATLAB Polar Plots

Tags: matlab, plot, histogram, polar-coordinates

I'm using polar plots (POLAR(THETA,RHO)) in MATLAB.

Is there an easy way to fix the range for the radial axis to say, 1.5?

I'm looking for something analogous to the xlim, ylim commands for cartesian axes. Haven't found anything in the docs yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's how I was able to do it.

The MATLAB polar plot (if you look at the Handle Graphics options available) does not have anything like xlim or ylim.  However, I realized that the first thing plotted sets the range, so I was able to plot a function with radius range [-.5 .5] on a [-1 1] plot as follows:

```
theta  = linspace(0,2*pi,100);
r      = sin(2*theta) .* cos(2*theta);
r_max  = 1;
h_fake = polar(theta,r_max*ones(size(theta)));
hold on;
h      = polar(theta, r);
set(h_fake, 'Visible', 'Off');
```

That doesn't look very good and hopefully there's a better way to do it, but it works.

Comment: That's clever. Thanks.
I'm surprised they don't provide a more direct control over radius.

Comment: Me too - I wouldn't think that wanting to tweak the radius would be *that* rare

Comment: I've come up with the same solution.  Unfortunately, they don't define a polar plot as a base graph type, instead creating patches to draw the axes and transforming your data into x and y.  Take a look at the code for polar.m sometime and you'll see.

Comment: As Scottie T mentions above, a polar plot is actually just a bunch of patch, line, and text objects drawn on an invisible Cartesian graph. You can take a peek at all the little graphics objects that form the polar plot by "unhiding" their handles with the following: 
>> kids = get(gca,'Children')  % Display the current axes children >> set(0,'ShowHiddenHandles','on'); 
>> hiddenKids = get(gca,'Children')  % Display the hidden children too

Answer (score 8):

this worked for me... i wanted the radius range to go to 30, so i first plotted this

```
polar(0,30,'-k')
hold on
```

and then plotted what i was actually interested in.  this first plotted point is hidden behind the grid marks.  just make sure to include

```
hold off
```

after your final plotting command.

Comment: I appreciate the simplicity of this answer. Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 6):

Simple solution is to make a fake graph and set its color to white.

```
fake=100;
polar(0,fake,'w');
hold on;

real=10;
polar(0,real,'w');
```

Answer (score 4):

In case anyone else comes across this, here's *the* solution:

As ***Scottie T*** and ***gnovice*** pointed out, Matlab basically uses the polar function as an interface for standard plots, but with alot of formatting behind the scenes to make it look polar.  Look at the values of the XLim and YLim properties of a polar plot and you'll notice that they are literally the x and y limits of your plot in Cartesian coordinates.  So, to set a radius limit, use xlim and ylim, or axis, and be smart about the values you set:

```
rlim = 10;
axis([-1 1 -1 1]*rlim);
```

...that's all there is to it.  Happy Matlabbing :)