# MATLAB rose plot: increasing radial increments?

Tags: matlab, graphics, plot, histogram, polar-coordinates

I am producing many angle histogram plots using rose2.m. I would like the scale showing the number of elements in each bin to range between 0-50, increasing by increments of 10, for all plots, even if the max number of elements on a particular plot is less than 50. Does anyone know how I can do this please? Thanks.

Comment: I assume you are using the rose2.m for filled angle histogram plots found here: http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-34DNFL/index.html?product=ML&solution=1-34DNFL

Answer (score 1):

This question is the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226315/fixing-the-radial-axis-on-matlab-polar-plots) but you are looking at a special case of `rose2`.

I was able to lock the max value to 50 with the following code. First I plot an empty point at 50 then `hold on` to lock the plot. `rose2` then uses those bounds.

The code:

```
x = (rand(100,1)*pi);

maxHistogramValue = 50;

figure(44);
clf
% Set the max value to maxHistogramValue:
polar(0, maxHistogramValue,'-k')
hold on;

% Now use rose2:
rose2(x);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another example (based on [@Steve](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11251140/97160)'s idea):

```
%# data and angular histogram
x = rand(400,1) .* 2*pi;
[t,r] = rose(x);                %# this does not generate a plot

%# set plot's max radial ticks
figure
rMax = 50;
h = polar(0, rMax);
delete(h)
set(gca, 'Nextplot','add')

%# draw patches instead of lines: polar(t,r)
[x,y] = pol2cart(t,r);
h = patch(reshape(x,4,[]), reshape(y,4,[]), 'b');
alpha(h, 0.5)       %# note: this switches to OpenGL renderer
```

[image: screenshot]

This way you get to control the maximum radius, though you can't really control the number of steps (POLAR function always prefers around 5 radial ticks; see the source code).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely clear on what rose2.m is, but I'd imagine that you can set your own scale/legend if you have the necessary data to do so.

It sounds like you have an array/vector of angle that range between 0 and 50.  We'll call that angleArray for now.

To get the number of elements that fall into each bin (0-50 in 10 unit incriments) you can use the following line of code:

```
binCounts = histc(angleArray, 0:10:50);
```

binCounts will be a 1 by n, where n is length(0:10:50) and have the counts of the number of values for each bin.  That data can then be used to populate your scale.