# Matlab Fix Compass Axis

Tags: matlab

```
compass(x,y);
```

How can I fix that 2.5 in this image to say 10.

[image]

Comment: what Matlab version are you using?

Comment: [A related post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226315/fixing-the-radial-axis-on-matlab-polar-plots)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a workaround:
First add a line of constant radius with the limit you want to have and then make it invisible:

```
Z = eig(randn(20,20));
h = compass(10 * ones(size(Z)));
set(h, 'Visible', 'off')
```

then add the data you actually want to plot:

```
hold on
compass(Z)
```

[image]

Comment: I'm using compass not polar

Comment: :) the answer remains the same though, see my edit.